# What is the story about Marisha daughter of Maharishi Kandu?

Tags: bhagavata-purana, indra, daksha

I believe Bhagvata Purana has the story on it. It goes something like Indra being afraid of Maharishi Kandu's tapasya ends up sending apsara Pralochana to seduce him. Kandu and Pralochana end up spending close to 1000 years together, and while leaving for Swargalok Pralochana's sweat drop gave birth to Marisha.

Now Marisha ends up marrying 10 Prachetas and this is how Daksha was reborn. Now my questions are 
1. What is this story about Daksha being reborn ?
2. We know Daksha's daughter is Aditi and she is mother of Indra. So was Indra who sent Pralochana a different Indra. If so, who are the two Indras ?